# 2ip.io/privacy/ and 'Defining tunnel (two way ping)' on SOCKS5 proxy

Tags: proxy, ubuntu, socks5

I was able to setup my first proxy server on Ubuntu 14 using danted. However, when I visit 2ip.io/privacy/

and run their privacy test, they return:

> Defining tunnel (two way ping) found

This is considered bad and reasoning the score 'Probability of anonymization 99%'
What is two way ping and how to prevent it showing up?

Comment: FWIW, this terminology is non-standard. I'm not sure what they are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

What this test means is that evidence of a VPN tunnel has been found by way of analyzing cipher timing signatures (ie, passive TCP/IP fingerprinting). Check out the following article for specifics relating to this type of fingerprinting and what you can do to protect yourself: https://medium.com/@ValdikSS/detecting-vpn-and-its-configuration-and-proxy-users-on-the-server-side-1bcc59742413

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with [the other](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/207626/139051) answer. Moreover, the article mentioned there is related to VPN fingerprint.
I also suggest an interesting scientific article: "[OpenVPN is Open to VPN FingerprintingOpenVPN is Open to VPN Fingerprinting](https://www.usenix.org/conference/usenixsecurity22/presentation/xue-diwen)"

So, what is this "`Defining tunnel (two way ping)`" ?
Tcpdump is our friend.

[image]

At first, they ping (echo request/reply, packets 1,2,3,5) your host, and if it replies they proceed with an [ICMP timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Timestamp).

All this is to check if the host is responsive to ICMP.
If this is the case, they send an OpenVPN message (packet 7, type: `P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2`) on the standard UDP port (1194).
The purpose of this message is to eventually get an ICMP Destination Unreachable message (packet 8) that COULD be a sign of a firewall blocking that port.

I didn't include other packets in the screenshot but they try doing the same thing for other well-known ports.

On today's Internet, in my opinion, this control makes no sense and results often in a false positive.
In any case, disabling ICMP on the WAN - if not needed - is always a good idea.